# Not receiving Web Server IP On Application Server

Tags: jakarta-ee

We have a J2EE based application. Following is architecture of the application.

There are two webservers one for internet and other for intranet. Request comes from browser, hit the Webserver and pass on to Application Server through a load balancer.

Application accessed from internet, reach to Application server through INTERNET WEBSERVER, whereas when  accessed from Intranet, request reach to application server through INTRANET WEB SERVER.

There are two sets of users who can access the application.

1. Internal Users, who should allow to access the application from Intranet environment only
2. External Users, who should allow to access the application from Internet environment only

To achieve this, we are validating the source of request by checking IP Address of Webserver. For this we are extracting the IP Address of webserver using request.getRemoteAddr method. But unfortunately, we are getting the IP address of INTRANET WEB SERVER only no matter whether application being accessed from Internet or Intranet.

Kindly suggest what could be the reason for this and how this can be rectified?

We are thinking to use some other mechanism to distinguish the request being arriving at application server from respective source (Web Server). Other option could be as follows;

1. Add Custom Header at Web Server
   a.  In this approach, a custom header will be added on both Internet and Intranet Webservers
   b.  Once request will reach to Application Server, system will check the header value and identify from which Web Server request has received
   c.  According to outcome of point 1.b, applications accessibility will be allowed to respective users
2. Validate Certificate and distinguish the request basis certificate
   a.  In this approach, both Internet and Intranet Webservers have different Certificate
   b.  Once request will reach to Application Server, system will check the certificate and identify from which server request has received
   c.  According to outcome of point 2.b, applications accessibility will be allowed to respective users

Please suggest if above solution can work and the mechanism to implement the same.

Details of Server is as follows;

Web Server: Oracle Http Server [Oracle Fusion Middleware]
App Server: Oracle Weblogic 11g

I hope, I could provide all the required information in detail. Do let me know in case any other detail is required.

We would be thankful for your help.

Thanks and Regards,
Rahul Srivastava

Comment: "But unfortunately, we are getting the IP address of INTRANET WEB SERVER only no matter whether application being accessed from Internet or Intranet." this cant be actually. Are you sure you are not maybe proxing something?

Comment: I don't think so because in Application Server's access log we intermittently received IP address of Internet Web Server as well, however still could not receive that address in Servlet using request.getRemoteAddr. What could be the reason?

Comment: javadoc: getRemoteAddr()
          Returns the Internet Protocol (IP) address of the client or last proxy that sent the request.   You should have seen the internet Server

Comment: i don't know, maybe try to use getRemoteHost()

Comment: ohh wait, you probably get the ip of the load balancer

Comment: maybe you can use this: `String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");  
   if (ipAddress == null) {  
    ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();  
   }`

Comment: I've already used all permutation combination of different kind of headers like X_Forwarded-For etc. But no luck. That is why thinking to use some other approach like adding custom header add web server level or validate certificate. Please suggest the way ahead.

Comment: then simply print entire request and look what do you have there

Comment: so what's about ip, is it from your load balancer?

Comment: No, getting IP of intranet Webserver only.

Comment: didn't you say the webserver passes the request through the load-balancer? could it be, that your load-balancer is running on the same machine as webserver?

Comment: No, load balancer is separate from both the webservers. We are  suspecting that there might be some conjunction in the path between Internet Webserver and Intranet Webserver. But don't know how to prove/find this? This architecture is in Production and we don't have direct access of it.