# Add Request/Response Header in Oracle HTTP WebServer

Tags: java, web-applications, weblogic

In my J2ee based application which is deployed on Oracle Weblogic 11g AS, request comes from two Oracle HTTP Web Server. One is meant for Intranet and other is for Internet users. I want to figure out from whether request is coming from Internet web server or Intranet web server. Basis this, access of application being restricted.

Can we add some request header at Oracle HTTP Web Server side which can be check in servlet once request will reach to Application server?

Idea is that we'll add request header in both the web servers with different value. Once request will reach to application server, we'll check the value of this header and identify from which web server request is coming from. Accordingly access right will be provided to the users accessing the application from internet or intranet.

Please suggest if any other solution can meet the requirement.

Comment: you should be able to identify it based on IP from where request is coming

Comment: Already tried this, but not getting correct IP.

Comment: elaborate it please, why and how it is not working

Comment: Please see, another question posted with regards to same. All details are available there. "Not receiving Web Server IP On Application Server"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712355/not-receiving-web-server-ip-on-application-server

Comment: Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327219/verifying-if-request-source-comes-from-internet-or-intranet And the oracle docs on network connection filters http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13711/con_filtr.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could separate the traffic using networks channel. (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13701/network.htm)

For instance register a new HTTP channel for the WLS Managed Server and point one HTTP server to this new port.

Then you could implement a Weblogic filter the achieve the expected behavior. (http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2011/03/03/weblogic-connection-filters/)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. I went through the docs but could not figure out how it can solve the problem in hand. Kindly elaborate and assist further.